# Sharepoint 2010 refinement dates by year

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, date, advanced-search

I'm need to implement a cutom refinement to allow the user to "drill down" by year(I have a date field) in the search result. Is this even possible to do that with out a calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

- Go to your search result page and edit it.
- Edit the properties of the Refinement web part In the toolbox (on the right)
- You should see a field for your filters. Click the ellipsis (...) next to it.

This will show you the XML for your filters. There'll already be one for last modified. You can then add another filter for the managed metadata column for your search result. You'll need to consider if you want the available filters to be relative (e.g. "Last Year") or absolute ("2011")

```
<CustomFilters MappingType="RangeMapping" DataType="Date" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
<CustomFilter CustomValue="2011">
    <OriginalValue>1/1/2011..12/31/2011</OriginalValue>
</CustomFilter>
<CustomFilter CustomValue="2009-2010">
    <OriginalValue>1/1/2009..12/31/2010</OriginalValue>
</CustomFilter>
```

See http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/10/custom-refinement-filters-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thx Andy, but I want to avoid "hard coding" the years..since I can't know which date will be in the my date column.

Comment: Yeah, then I think you'd have to use relative, rather than absolute, dates. Or maybe write your own refinement control (which can be done, but is definitely a developer activity).